# python error AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'WNOHANG'

Tags: python, operating-system

When I import the module 'geocat.comp' the error AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'WNOHANG'. But the 'os' module has been bulit when python was bulit. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZlhM.png)

I don't know why. Could you please give me some suggestions and tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the library you are using does not support Windows (yet).
See [this particular issue](https://github.com/NCAR/geocat-comp/issues/131) from the geocat-comp repo.

Also, [please avoid pasting error messages as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).